# Google Visualization Dashboard: getChart() null object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

in google visualization i have implemented a dashboard, with one table and some controls filters.

In the html i have added a button and when i click on that i want get all selected rows: the problem is that the function getChart() return a null object: why?

Where i must implement the onclick function?

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls', "corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Status');

    data.addRows([
      ['Customer1', 'Active'],
      ['Customer2', 'Blocked'],
    ]);

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    var stringNameFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'StringFilter',
        'containerId': 'filterName_div',
        'options': {
          'filterColumnIndex': 0,
          'ui': {
            'label': '',
            }
        }
     });

    // Define a table
    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Table',
      'containerId': 'table_div',
      'options': {
          'allowHtml': true,
      }

    });

    dashboard.bind(stringNameFilter, table);
    dashboard.draw(data);

    document.getElementById("btn_solicit").onclick = function() {
        var tmpData = table.getChart();
                    ...

    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getChart` method will return `null` until the visualization wrapped by the ChartWrapper finishes drawing.  Try wrapping the event handler code in a one-time "ready" event listener:

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    document.getElementById("btn_solicit").onclick = function() {
        var tmpData = table.getChart();
        // ...
    };
});
```

Place that after creating `table` but before calling `dashboard.draw`.